# passing value of a variable to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs, I am learning directives, and I am trying to pass value to the directive but the thing was not working.

**html**

```
<genericsearch objectType="tei_org" organisationSearch="organisationSearchEvent"></genericsearch>
```

**directive**

```
directive('genericsearch', [function () {
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        objectType : '=',

      },
     controller: ['$scope','$element','$rootScope','SearchOrg','MapOrgs','$routeParams','DelOrgs','GetTemplateGroups','FetchOrgs', function($scope,$element,$rootScope,SearchOrg,MapOrgs,$routeParams,DelOrgs,GetTemplateGroups,FetchOrgs){
        $scope.getOrgs = function(objectType, event) {
          if(event.keyCode != 13){
            //$scope.Participants(data);
           $scope.organisationSearchEvent(objectType);
          }
        }
        $scope.organisationSearchEvent = function(filter,objectType){
          SearchOrg().fetch({'filter':filter, 'searchType':objectType}).$promise.then(

          function(value){
            $scope.orgList = value.data;

          },
          function(err){

          });
      }
   }],
    templateUrl : TAPPLENT_CONFIG.HTML_ENDPOINT[0]+'home/search.html'

}
}])
```

Comment: what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the thing is i need to pass tei_org to organizationsearchEvent eventhandler how to do this by using $scope i cant able to do it. please help me

Comment: I think the attribute should be object-type in html not objectType. That plus what Rouby said

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misinterpret the $scope and / or how to pass values onto functions.

The $scope of your controller has a property `objectType`. You dont need to add this as a parameter to the functions inside the controller.

Instead you simply access it via `$scope.objectType`.

E.g.

```
$scope.organisationSearchEvent = function(filter){
          SearchOrg().fetch({'filter':filter, 'searchType':$scope.objectType}).$promise.then(

          function(value){
            $scope.orgList = value.data;

          },
          function(err){

          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you can use a link function within your directive controllers.

**Html**

```
<genericsearch objectType="tei_org" organisationSearch="organisationSearchEvent"></genericsearch>
```

**Directive**

```
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs) {    
       scope.myParam = attrs.organisationSearch; 
      }
```

After that, you can access to myParam in your controller via your scope

Comment: This is already covered by angular with the scope settings on the directive.

Comment: @harrini Take a look at my answer, this answer is not your solution I think.

Answer (score -1):

This is where you use link and pass it to your controller.

Html:

```
<my-fancy-directive my-attribute="something"></my-fancy-directive>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive('myFancyDirective', function() {
   restrict:'E',
   replace:true,
   controller:function($scope){
      $scope.theAttribute = "";
   },

   link:function(scope,elem,attr) {
      attr.$observe('myAttribute',function(newValue,oldValue){
          if(newValue != oldValue)
             scope.theAttribute = newValue;
      })
   }
});
```

Bonus tip: to remember the variables in the linkfunction, just think of "sea". Scope, Element, Attributes

Comment: You dont need $observe, thats what the scope-definition does and is for.

Comment: Also I think this answer does not address the root of the question, instead it just provides a different approach.

Comment: Sorry, obviously just read "I am trying to pass value to the directive but the thing was not working" and figured. On the $observe, you would need it if the attribute value changes.

Comment: Scope Definition '=' is a two way binding and tracks changes. That's what the original code uses.